# A symbol that is like fused version of less than and parallel

Tags: math-mode

I want the following symbol (and its right variant). I tried searching for it (on detexify as well) but I could not find it.

[image]

I tried to combine `<` and `\parallel` (and `\triangleleft` and `|`) but I could not get the size adjustment right.

Comment: Perhaps you may check [this document](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Looks like U+29CF ⧏ to me. I think `stix` has `\ltrivb`.

Comment: Its right variant is \vbrtri.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: I don't want to change the font family. Is there a way, perhaps just by combining `\lefttriangle` and `\mid` in some way that works?

Comment: You could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to let us know which font or package you are using for math symols. This might make things a bit easier. In the end, I guess that the symbol should match the other symbols you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't go with `unicode-math`, you can resort to your original idea.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\fltrivb}{}{%
  <%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\scaled@parallel\relax
  }%
}
\newcommand{\scaled@parallel}[2]{%
  \mkern-\scaled@parallel@kern{#1}mu
  \vcenter{
    \m@th
    \sbox\z@{$#1<$}%
    \hbox{%
      \resizebox{\width}{\dimeval{\ht\z@+\dp\z@}}{%
        \raisebox{\depth}{$#1\parallel$}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\scaled@parallel@kern}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 4.5\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle 4.5\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 4.6\else
  5.1\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptstyle A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fltrivb B$

\large
$A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptstyle A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fltrivb B$

\footnotesize
$A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptstyle A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fltrivb B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version with also the symmetric symbol.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\fltrivb}{}{%
  <%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\scaled@parallel{r}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fvbrtri}{}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\scaled@parallel{l}%
  }%
  >%
}
\newcommand{\scaled@parallel}[2]{%
  \if r#2\mkern-\scaled@parallel@kern{#1}mu\fi
  \vcenter{
    \m@th
    \sbox\z@{$#1<$}%
    \hbox{%
      \resizebox{\width}{\dimeval{\ht\z@+\dp\z@}}{%
        \raisebox{\depth}{$#1\parallel$}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \if l#2\mkern-\scaled@parallel@kern{#1}mu\fi
}
\newcommand{\scaled@parallel@kern}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 4.5\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle 4.5\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 4.6\else
  5.1\fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptstyle A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fltrivb B$

{\large
$A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptstyle A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fltrivb B$\par}

{\footnotesize
$A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptstyle A\fltrivb B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fltrivb B$\par}

$A\fvbrtri B$ $\scriptstyle A\fvbrtri B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fvbrtri B$

{\large
$A\fvbrtri B$ $\scriptstyle A\fvbrtri B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fvbrtri B$\par}

{\footnotesize
$A\fvbrtri B$ $\scriptstyle A\fvbrtri B$ $\scriptscriptstyle A\fvbrtri B$\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how to do the kind of code you used, and I tried making modifications but I could not make the right variant. Can you add it in the answer, (or perhaps provide me a link from where I could understand the code and do it myself)?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Added. The kern should go to the other side.

Answer (score 3):

These symbols are in Unicode math table (U+029CF and U+029D0), but only few math Unicode fonts provide it. For example XITSMath does it. You can try in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[xits]
$a \ltrivb b \vbrtri c$
\bye
```

Comment: I don't want to change the font family. Is there a way, perhaps just by combining `\lefttriangle` and `\mid` in some way that works?

Comment: You can combine more Unicode math fonts in single document. The main math font used for almost all characters (visually compatible with main text font family) and additional math font only for selected characters. In OpTeX, additional math font can be loaded by `\addUmathfont \xits {[XITSMath-Regular]}{} {[XITSMath-Bold]}{} {}` and then you can set missing characters by `\mathchars`. See `https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/math-doc.pdf`, section 12, for more details.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 NewCM-Book provides all the unicode symbols, including the ones you want. NewCM is basically a clone/huge extension of CM. https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern